# How to locate a body that does not have static id and put a text in?

Tags: ruby

i try to fill with a text on this with watirwebdriver jetbrains ruby:

```
<body id=":fa" class="editable LW-avf" style="min-width: 0px; width: 487px; border: 0px none; margin: 0px;…t: 100%; overflow: hidden; direction: ltr; min-height: 84px;" hidefocus="true" g_editable="true" role="textbox"></body>
```

This is my code

```
b.body(:class => 'editable LW-avf').send_keys 'Esta es una prueba'
```

and i get the following errors...

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.8/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:490:in `assert_exists': unable to locate element, using {:class=>"editable LW-avf", :tag_name=>"body"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.8/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:302:in `send_keys'
    from C:/Users/GETECSA/RubymineProjects/SMS/controllerRV.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: in this case, can you not just specify that it is the body tag? There should only be one.

Comment: but the body id changes constantly and the class is unable to locate how i take the body to fill with a text?

Comment: what return `b.element(:class => 'editable LW-avf')` ?

Comment: With .set the following error C:\Ruby193\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) C:/Users/G ETECSA/RubymineProjects/SMS/controllerRV.rb
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.8/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:553:in `method_missing': undefined method `set' for #<Watir::HTMLElement:0x38616a8> (NoMethodError)
 from C:/Users/GETECSA/RubymineProjects/SMS/controllerRV.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
 from -e:1:in `load'
 from -e:1:in `<main>'

Comment: With .send_keys returns:from [remote server] file:///driver_component.js:8879:in `FirefoxDriver.annotateInvalidSelectorError_': The given selector editable LW-avf is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred: (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError)
InvalidSelectorError: Compound class names not permitted i can not text all because is very extensive